# determining a complex function from the jump at its branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f(z)$ with branch cut $[-1,1]$. Suppose we know its jump at the branch cut, i.e., we know

$$ h(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+ } [ f(x+ i \epsilon ) - f(x -i \epsilon ) ]$$

for $-1\leq x \leq 1$. To what extent can we determine $f$? Of course, $f$ can differ by an entire function. But is there anything more we can say? Is this related to the Riemann-Hilbert problem?